# relay life time

Tags: microcontroller, relay, nodemcu

I am developing a home automation system using nodemcu esp8266. For this I want to use srd-03vdc-sl-c relay to control my appliances with nodemcu. But I am not sure that how long this system will work and I want to know how long the relay support for the system.
Anyone please help me,

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the releay data sheet. There should be a section about maximum switching number, frequency, ...

Comment: What do you mean with "how long the relay support for the system."

Comment: By typing the part number you provided into Google, you get the datasheet, which has a graph of lifetime as a function of load current and the number of operations.

Answer (score 1):

Life is highly dependent on the type of load. If it's almost entirely resistive (including the wiring to the load) you can **usually** depend on the curves in the datasheet, but only if you use a zener + diode or other high voltage snubber across the coil- they are not generally rated for life with a simple flyback diode.

If you're switching a power supply input (such as an LED or CFL bulb) or a tungsten bulb or a motor, you may have significantly decreased life. In such cases it would be wise to use a better relay that has defined life for that specific type of load, rather than such a < 25¢ relay.

This particular relay has a TV-5 rating, for which you can look up the specifications, which allows some inrush current etc. At 6A/120VAC life is 40,000 operations vs. 250,000 operations with a resistive load.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the datasheet and depending on the currency for (AC120V/DC24V, cos(fi)=1)

1A - 700k ops

12A - 80k ops

For more information you can check on [datasheet page](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/720555/Songle/SRD-03VDC-SL-C/1)